# shell script is not writing module list command to a file instead printing to screen

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

My shell script is not writing the loaded modules to a file , instead it is printing on the screen.

This is my code snippet of my shell script:

```
load module A
load module B
modulelist=$(module list)
if [ -f "$dest" ]
then 
    echo "File found...."
    echo "Appending to the file keeping previous data....please wait."
    echo -e "$modulelist" >> "$dest"
    echo -e "$newline" >> "$dest"
    echo "Successfully written all outputs to the file....please move it to /root/ directory."
fi
```

All the other outputs are written to the file but not this command.
Please tell me what is wrong in my code.

Comment: How do you invoke the script?  Are you redirecting `stdout` to a file?

Comment: i am doing echo -e $msg >> $file

Comment: i am running by "source run_config.sh "

Comment: To make completely sure: are you saying that `echo -e "$modulelist" >> "$dest"` prints the value of the `modulelist` variable to the terminal, instead of appending it to the file whose name is in the `dest` variable? There seems to be nothing in the code you're showing that could make that happen.

Comment: yes i am doing echo -e to send output to the file whose path is stored in $dest

Comment: yes echo -e is printing the value to terminal rather than to file

Comment: Are you sure it's not just because `module list` is in fact writing to standard error? see for example [How do I capture the module command output?](https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FAQ.html#how-do-i-capture-the-module-command-output)

Comment: It is printing like this in the screen: Currently loaded modules: 1)A 2)B there is no error